# Is this a naive blocking queue?

Tags: concurrency, rust, blockingqueue

Is the following a correct implementation of a blocking queue ?

Correct as in:

1. Thread-safe, i.e., has the semantics of a queue in a multi thread scenario.
2. If empty, blocks if trying to retrieve an element.
3. If full (`std::u8::MAX` in this case), blocks if trying to add a new element.

From my static analysis, I would say it is safe from dead locks; but I know how tricky synchronization can be.

Is there anything obviously wrong with this implementation that would prevent me to use in production?  (hypothetical scenario)
If this implementation is correct, what are the performance drawbacks compared to a proper `BlockingQueue`, and why?

Code

```rust
use std::collections::VecDeque;
use crate::Semaphore;
use std::sync::Mutex;

pub struct BlockingQueue<T> {
    non_empty_queue: Semaphore,
    bounded_queue: Semaphore,
    data: Mutex<VecDeque<T>>
}

impl<T> BlockingQueue<T> {
    pub fn poll(&self) -> T {
        self.non_empty_queue.decrement();
        let mut lock_guard = self.data.lock().expect("Unable to acquire lock ...");
        let result = lock_guard.pop_back().expect("Major flaw!");
        self.bounded_queue.increment();
        result
    }

    pub fn offer(&self, t: T) -> () {
        self.bounded_queue.decrement();
        let mut lock_guard = self.data.lock().expect("Unable to acquire lock ...");
        lock_guard.push_front(t);
        self.non_empty_queue.increment();
    }

    pub fn new() -> BlockingQueue<T> {
        BlockingQueue {
            non_empty_queue: Semaphore::new(0),
            bounded_queue: Semaphore::new(std::u8::MAX),
            data: Mutex::new(VecDeque::new())
        }
    }
}
```

Notes:

1. The Semaphore is of my own creation. Lets just assume it is correctly implemented.
2. `bounded_queue` attempts to prevent insertions beyond `std::u8::MAX`.
3. `non_empty_queue` attemps to prevent "pops" when empty.

Comment: This question might be more suitable for [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) partner site, though I don't know how active the Rust community is there. Concerning the actual question, just a pointer: The optimal implementation of a parallel queue is very much dependent on the problem it solves. Typical approaches are either bulk operations or lock-freedom, implemented with atomics (see e. g. [here](https://docs.rs/crossbeam-queue/0.2.3/src/crossbeam_queue/array_queue.rs.html), crossbeams version).

Comment: If this is a learning exercise, it seems fine. If you are really asking whether to use this in production, I would recommend to go with [crossbeam channels](https://lib.rs/crates/crossbeam-channel), which are faster under load because they use lock-free primitives, and which have received intense scrutiny and testing.